# how to perform a UNION where some tables are empty

Tags: sql, sas, union

I wish to perform a UNION between 3 tables, where I know that 1 of them has no values (empty table).
I get an ERROR using SAS PROC SQL:
ERROR: Table WORK.B doesn't have any columns.

My code:

```
select *
from work.A
union 
select *
from work.B
union 
select *
from work.C
```

To my understanding, I need to use EXIST, in order to UNION only existing tables.

Comment: The error is not that table B is empty but Table WORK.B doesn't have any columns. I am not sure about SAS but for union you should select same number of columns in same order and with same datatype from all the tables. So if you are using * then table structure of both A and B should be same

Comment: What's the point of unioning an empty table, though?

Comment: @metadata all the tables have same number of columns and same types and order, the issue is because table B is empty.

Comment: when I perform the SQL, I don't know whether a table will be empty or not.

Comment: Try using column names in select instead of *

Comment: @MetaData doesn't work.

Comment: Quite interesting . . . Most databases don't allows tables with no columns.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log ERROR message also states `PROC SQL requires each of its tables to have at least 1 column.`

You can stack (union) your data with a `DATA` step `SET` statement and then `SORT` away duplicates.

Example:

```
data x;
  set sashelp.class (where=(name=:'A'));

data y;
  stop;

data z;
  retain age weight name height;
  set sashelp.class (where=(name in: ('A', 'J')));
run;

data want;
  set x y z;
run;

proc sort data=want nodupkey;
  by _all_;
run;
```

Comment: For some reason, SQL does not allow UNION when a table is "not created" do to no obs. but using the SET statement in a data step covers it! THANKS!!